# Purpose of oscilloscope

Tags: embedded

So I am starting to accumilate my research for getting into embedded systems. I was told that it would be advantageous to get a oscilloscope.

Can someone give me a brief explanation of what it does and its application in embedded systems?

It seems I have a flawed understanding.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, even though embedded programmers at times do use oscilloscopes. They are used to observe the electric signals at different points of your device. That can help debugging things like device drivers, find hardware bugs, etc.

Comment: ok... 
"can help debugging things like device drivers, find hardware bugs,"

... so how did that not pertain to programming.

Comment: Um... You kind of got me there. OTOH, if you have to ask this question, you probably don't have enough electrical engineering or physics background and when you start asking questions about electronics, you should use the more appropriate stackexchange sites.

Comment: I disagree, I think this is a plenty fine site to ask this question.

Comment: Keeping the hardware in place and the lights on is also useful for all those things but they aren't related to programming either. A scope is used to observe the behaviour of *hardware*.

Comment: This _is_ a programming question!!! You cannot do professional embedded programming without an oscilloscope! It is perfectly fine to ask questions about programmer tools at this site.

Comment: @EJP One of the most common uses of oscilloscopes are used to measure software execution time, and to find performance issues in the source code. Or to look for interrupt latency issues. You don't use some fluff "profiling" program for low-level embedded software, you use an oscilloscope. How exactly is software execution time, interrupt latency and detecting needs of source code optimization related to hardware?

Comment: @Lundin I don't know what the most common uses of oscilloscopes are. I don't imagine you do either. I own two, and I participate in scope forums where I have never seen software debugging mentioned even once. The use you mention does exist of course; however you seem to be answering the OP's actual question, but in the strange form of adverse comments against other people. Perhaps you should answer the question itself?

Comment: @EJP I use a scope on daily basis. If you ever work with realtime embedded systems, you will find yourself using a scope to measure software execution times quite often. Same thing if you ever use microcontroller timer peripherals. I'm curious to know what you are using to measure execution time, if not a scope?

Comment: @Lundin I *have* worked in embedded realtime systems, as long ago as 1981, and I *didn't* use a scope. The hardware design engineer did. And what you do every day doesn't prove anything about most the  most common uses of scopes. I also use one every day, for something else, which also doesn't prove anything. It is just anecdote, not evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many uses depending on the problem being solved.  A common use would be for debugging i2c, spi, mdio and other serial busses and their protocols.  These interfaces allow from some creativity from the hardware engineers so as a result the software has to make sure it is sending the right bits in the right order at the right rate, for bidirectional lines turning the bus around at the right time so the other side can drive, etc.  All of this is visible on the scope.  You can figure out if the reason why something is not working is because of your code or because of the hardware or because of some information that was not properly communicated between the parties, the correct i2c address for example.

Another not so uncommon use is for debugging, for example am I really entering the interrupt service routine.  Add a line to wiggle a gpio bit, look for that bit on the scope, perhaps look at the timing between that bit and the external event that caused it, (assuming it was an external event).  Perhaps determine that you may have a latency problem, maybe you need some assembly to speed up the reaction time, that kind of thing.

Getting a scope yourself before even knowing what you are going to do with it is perhaps not the right thing to do.  It depends on where you are in this process of moving into this world.  If you are in an independent contractor, sure at some point, if you work for someone they should already have this equipment if they want to be or remain successful in this business.  At the same time, all too often, the right equipment is not available to the engineers and you have to get creative to do the job so, an important lesson is getting by without the proper equipment.  Perhaps the gpio example above is a workaround for not having the equipment or development software/environment, etc you wanted/needed for the job.

Datasheets and users manuals always have some errors or missing information.  It is quite often that a divide by 2 on a clock tree is not documented well enough and you cant figure out why your serial port is not working.  get out the scope, measure the time on the signal, perhaps change the code to make it a different baud rate, see how that changes the signal on the scope, figure out if you are off by 2 or 4 (usually the case), etc.  Knowing the answer, to the clock rate produced might bring that ahh ha moment in what the manual was trying to describe or what one of the pictures is showing but not mentioned anywhere in the text.  One of the manuals I recently used had that exact thing the text said this clock is divided by two for everyone, but one picture, only one, mentioned timers being that clock times 2, effectively not divided.  By experimenting I understood, what the reality was.  If you run off and write many thousands of lines of code based on manuals without experimenting on the real hardware you are in for weeks or months of debugging.  The scope at least in part helps.

The short answer is that with a desktop computer or laptop or phone or other smart device you have a user interface, keyboard, mouse, display, touch screen, etc.  In embedded you sometimes have a serial port and some leds to blink, but often not, and to get the serial port working you have to get the thing booting which takes a scope if there are problems, debug the flash, make sure the data is in there with the right endianness, etc.  Then debug the serial port clock speed, if the manual for the device is lacking.  the oscilloscope is your monitor or display for embedded programs. like an lcd panel or computer monitor is to writing gui applications.

Comment: Good, thorough explanation.  But note that all of the above tasks like debugging I2C/SPI, and wiggling gpios are better suited to a logic analyzer than an oscope.  Scopes allow you to debug analog signals.  For the same cost of a 2-channel scope, you could get a logic analyzer with many more channels, and possibly auto-decoding of many protocols.  You can get a good USB logic analyzer that just hooks to a PC, like this: http://www.nci-usa.com/frame_products_overview.htm

Comment: the logic analyzer wont show you when the shared data line has gone from driven to high z back to driven by someone else.  Logic analyzers are good too, I would argue they are as important depending on the product/protocols.  the oscopes out there are doing protocol decoding now.  I argue against using that but that is an old school opinion perhaps.    the oscope will do the logic level stuff and analog where the logic analyzer will only do the logic level stuff and you have to assume the signal was good, you dont get to see the quality of the signal just an interpreted true/false.

Comment: the logic analyzer pays for itself when you need to look at logic signals with more than a few signals, very useful.  The big problem with logic analyzers today is you need to design your pcb for them, you really have to put a header on the board to connect the analyzer, you cant use a chip clip on a bga part.  most parts that have enough signals to need a logic analyzer are bga now or going to be.  I do agree with you though for the money you can get a good logic anayzer, or even make your own from an eval microcontroller board.

Comment: All true, really depends on your needs.  There are also some mixed signal scopes that give a combination of analog and digital channels.  Not super cheap, but you can find decent deals on ebay

Comment: I think the first set of "tools" you need for embedded are serial ports (since most computers dont have them anymore) a set of cables or ability to make custom serial cables and jtag wigglers depending on the target processors.  oscopes and logic analyzers the hardware folks should be worrying about.

Comment: informative explanation.